# HDR color problem on MacBook Pro 16" 2019

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, hdr

I am watching same video on a Mac and two phones, iPhone 12 and Android.

There is abnormal glare on the Mac. For example in attached pics the Mac shows too much glare on girls face, clothes.

This happens when I play [this video](https://youtu.be/2RIDhA9c8qw?t=10) in HDR in Chrome, it does not happen if HDR not enabled in Safari.

How do I solve this problem ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd try improving the color calibration of your display.

Comment: @benwiggy it happens on hdr videos only

Answer (score 6):

The trouble with colour is you need to know the start point & you need your workflow to be correctly calibrated & profiled..

I'm not so sure that YouTube is a great start point, as there is no constant definition of how anything is encoded.
After that you get the issue of each device decoding & interpreting differently.
You can only fix this with accurate calibration & profiling using a hardware colorimeter. [This is not cheap, maybe $£€ 250 for a decent one].

From the youtube info on that video…

> To view this video in real HDR you need a 4K HDR TV and a device with YouTube HDR such as Chromecast Ultra.
> If you are viewing this video on an SDR (normal non-HDR TV) the color and contrast may not look correct.

I have one of those LG OLED 4k TVs, but I don't have a chromecast, so I can't view it on there. What I do have, though is a fully-calibrated workflow on my Mac.

So, this is what it looks like on there, in standard HD…

[image]

Which, of course, you can only see the same as I do if your display is also fully-calibrated ;)
However, compared to both your Mac & iPhone pictures to me looks more natural [It's still over-punchy & nothing like "real life", but at least the white point looks acceptable]. Your Mac image is even more contrasty & has a yellow cast. The iPhone image is heavily over-saturated & has a yellow deficit, leaving red & blue too hot.
I'm surprised the phone isn't closer to accurate, out of the box they tend to be reasonably close. I have never, though, seen a laptop screen that wasn't set up badly, unless it's been accurately profiled.  What we're seeing of the phone image, of course, is a photo of its screen taken on another device, meaning we have one, possibly two, further places where the colour-management is poor.

As you don't have the recommended hardware to view HDR, then I wouldn't try to view things that way.
If you could post further images of how they look in SDR, that could be an interesting comparison.
[BTW, my personal opinion of HDR as a semi-pro colour "almost-expert" is that it completely messes up what might have been a really nice picture;)
My LG TV has also been calibrated & all this "clever" stuff switched off, because it's just horrible.

*Edit*
I just noticed you said it looks worse in Chrome - that's not a surprise. Chrome ignores so much of the Mac standard toolbox I'm surprised anyone puts up with it.

This is taken on the same screen from Chrome - yup, it looks worse. I would expect it to look worse because of Chrome's flagrant disregard for colour profiling. This is not fixable, even with calibration.

[image]

*Some background qualification, in case my opinions seem too… opinionated;)*
I'm a keen semi-pro photographer, used to working in a fully-calibrated environment - every screen in the house has been accurately profiled. I work in the TV/film industry so I am very used to also seeing correct colour imagery on real professional displays, day in, day out. (By 'real professional' I mean 30 grand for a 21" display;)

Comment: _"Your Mac image is even more contrasty & has a yellow cast"_ — that's a photo, so this could be white imbalance by the camera. What is more prominent is that the image seems to have been supposed to be rendered on an HDR display, with e.g. the forehead having RGB values>1.0, but these values have been clipped instead of being HDR-rendered. The same problem with the bright blue parts of the dress. I don't know what software plays movies on Macs, but it seems to be misconfigured on the OP's machine, or actually incapable (if it's a third-party SW) of using the HDR screen.

Comment: @Ruslan - It's being played back on Chrome, notorious for poor colour [because it ignores any calibration/profiling]. We have to accept whatever the OP posts as 'accurate' imagery of their experience - no-one else can see what they see unless we all go round their house;) Without any form of calibration, Chrome's repro & the display's profiling are simply "random" interpretations. There is no such thing as an RGB value of >1, by definition. Colour spaces go from "zero to one" no matter what units or bit depth is used to describe them.

Comment: Your definition is only applicable to some color spaces like e.g. sRGB. Not so for [scRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/scRGB), where color values can be in the range [-0.5, 7.5].

Comment: You seem to be clutching at edge-case straws here. I'd never heard of scRGB until now. It's very probably not the world's most commonly-used colour space & appears to be Windows-centric. If you want a more common ultra-wide space, look at DCI-P3. There's still little chance of this being interpreted correctly on 99.9% of user displays, using a non-colour-compliant web browser & YouTube.

Comment: Not really. What I meant in the initial post is that the video frame colors are obviously clipped. This could happen if the frame was prepared in a color space where SDR frames would be in the range e.g. 0 .. *a*, and the HDR ones in 0 .. *ka*, and displayed in a wrong way on a surface that was configured to only handle the range 0 .. *a*. I just took *a* = 1.0 for simplicity.

Comment: So… you're agreeing with me, but in a "different way"?? btw, if both the OP's images are photos of displays, then relatively, my description still stands. Of course it's too hot, it's being badly interpreted by "whatever" in a completely uncalibrated workflow. There is no reference point at all. None. Nada. There's no measured start point & there's no measured end point. Random is what we are left with. "Looks like s**t" for want of a better phrase.

Comment: Well, yes, in a "different way". I was attempting to diagnose the most prominent problem (which is clipping ("glare" in the OP), not oversaturation, white point etc.), but I don't know anything of the Mac ecosystem, so can't actually point to the exact culprit.

Comment: Tetsujin is correct and further, please note that to half-way guarantee matching the display of colour on different devices, your choices are broadly to pay thousands for the training to do it yourself, or to pay hundreds at least and quite possibly thousands per instance for an expert to do it.